# Insert to mysql with undefined number of column

Tags: java, mysql, excel

I have a question about insert query of java.
I have read data from excel file, and I want to use that data to import to MySQL, if excel file has 3 columns, I can use

`String sql="INSERT INTO tablename(column1,column2,colum3) value(...)`

But if excel file doesn't have defined the number of column (for example `excel_1.xlsx` have 3 columns, `excel_2.xlsx` have 4 columns). 
How can I use insert query? Can anybody give me any suggestion?

Comment: How many columns does the database table actually have?

Comment: *Suggestion:* Build the SQL dynamically using string concatenation, escaping or sanitizing column names as necessary to prevent [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: database table's column dependent to excel file and it will be create by manual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File("yourExcelsheet.xsls"));
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);
Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();

//int columnCount = 4;  
String columnArray[] = new String[]{"column1","column2","column3","column4","column5","column6"};       

//iterate row-wise
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    String sql="INSERT INTO tablename";
    String columnNames = "";
    String valueString = "";
    String value = "";      
    int i=0;
    Row currentRow = iterator.next();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

    //iterate column-wise
     while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();     
        value = currentCell.getStringCellValue();

        if(i != 0)
        {
            columnNames += ",";
            valueString += ",";
        }
        columnNames += columnArray[i] ;
        valueString += value;
        i++;
    }

   sql += "(" + columnNames + ") values (" + valueString + ");";

   System.out.println(sql);

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

> INSERT INTO tablename(column1,column2,column3,column4) values
>   (5,5,5,5);